# Receiving raw image data through TCP for display using Qt

Tags: qt, tcp

I am working on a GUI to display image from sensor. The GUI acts as a client while the sensor acts as a server. Once I send a command to the sensor, the sensor will send streaming raw image data (binary data) continuously to the GUI through TCP. The data will be an exact copy of the image memory with size width (1240) x height (1028) coded in U8 (unsigned 8 bit). The size of one incoming data is (1240 x 1028 x 1 byte) + 20 byte (meta header) = 1.3MByte.

My biggest obstacles are:
1.) how can I receive and store the streaming data from sensor continuously for display purpose?
2.) how can I display the raw data?

I have tried the code as below, but it is not working. Please advise:

"client.h"

```
#ifndef CLIENT_H
#define CLIENT_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QTcpSocket>

class Client : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Client(QWidget *parent = 0);
    int capture (int mode, int NBRLine);

signals:

public slots:

private:
    QTcpSocket* socket;

};

#endif // CLIENT_H
```

"client.cpp"

```
#include "client.h"
#include <QHostAddress>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QtGui>
#include <QAbstractSocket>
#include <QImage>

Client::Client(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    socket = new QTcpSocket(this);  
}

int Client::capture(int mode, int NBRLine)
{
    if (socket->state() != QTcpSocket::ConnectedState)
    {
        socket->connectToHost("192.168.0.65", 1096);
    }

    /* send command to retrieve raw image data from sensor */
    if(socket->waitForConnected(5000))
    {
        QByteArray block;
        QDataStream out(&block, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
        out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_0);
        out.setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian);
        out << qint32(0) << qint32(0) << qint32(0) << qint32(1);
        out << qint32(9) << qint32(1) << qint32(0) << mode << qint32(10) << qint32(2) << qint32(0) << NBRLine ;
        socket->write(block);
        socket->flush();
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
    /**********************************************************/

    /* to get data size of each scan through width and height in the meta header */
    QDataStream input(socket);
    input.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_0);
    input.setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian);
    qint32 buffer, cmdID, counter, metaSize, width, height;
    do
    {
        if (socket->waitForReadyRead(1000))
        {
            input >> cmdID;
            if (cmdID == 101)
            {
                input >> buffer >>  buffer >> buffer >> buffer;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            socket->disconnectFromHost();
            break;

        }
    } while (cmdID != 1);

    input >> counter >> metaSize;
    if (metaSize != 8) return false;

    input >> width >> height;
    quint32 datasize =  width * height;

    /**********************************************************/

    /* Receiving streaming data which I have problem here !!!! */
    while (socket->bytesAvailable() < datasize + 80) {
        if (!socket->waitForReadyRead(1000)) {
            socket->disconnectFromHost();
            break;
        }
    }

    QImage img;
    input >> img;

    if (img.isNull())
    {
        return 0;
    }
    img.save("E:/temp1");
     return 1;
}
```

Comment: The class `QTcoSocket` has an incessant [readyRead()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qiodevice.html#readyRead) signal which can be connected to your data processor. For displaying raw data, [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797862/qt-c-converting-raw-binary-data-and-display-it-as-an-image-i-e-qimage) might help you.

Answer (score 2):

Before you can send the contents of the buffer, you need to find a way to tell the client how much data to expect. So first of all you should send data size and after that the data.

On the server side you should send image data like :

```
QTcpSocket socket;

QBuffer buffer;
QImageWriter writer(&buffer, "PNG");
writer.write(QImage("myImage.png") );

QByteArray data;
QDataStream stream( &data, QIODevice::WriteOnly );
stream.setVersion( QDataStream::Qt_4_8 );
stream << (quint32)buffer.data().size();
data.append( buffer.data() );

socket.write( data );
```

On the client side you should connect the `readyRead` signal of the socket to a slot to read data when new data receives :

```
connect( socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()),this, SLOT(tcpReady()) );
```

The image data can be read like :

```
void Client::tcpReady()
{
    if( dataSize == 0 )
    {
        QDataStream stream( &socket );
        stream.setVersion( QDataStream::Qt_4_8 );

        if( socket.bytesAvailable() < sizeof(quint32) )
            return;

        stream >> dataSize;
    }

    if( dataSize > socket.bytesAvailable() )
        return;

    QByteArray array = socket.read( dataSize );
    QBuffer buffer(&array);
    buffer.open( QIODevice::ReadOnly );

    QImageReader reader(&buffer, "PNG");
    QImage image = reader.read();

    if( !image.isNull() )
    {
        image.save("E:/temp1");
    }
    else
    {
        QDebug()<<"Invalid image received!";
    }
}
```

Comment: The response data that I will receive for each scan is like below:
<Cmd_ID (4 byte)> <Counter (4 byte)> <Size_of_Meta_Header (4 byte)> <Width (4 byte)>)> <Height (4 byte)> <Image Data>
First I need to check the value of Cmd_ID whether it is matched with the expected value. Then I need to calculate the size of image data by multiplying Width and Height. Normally the size of the image data is 1280 x 1024 byte = 1.3 Byte. So how can I apply your tcpReady() in my case? I used the method you showed me to read the data, but the QImage returns with NULL. What can be the cause here?

Comment: After reading your header, read the width and hight by : `stream >> imageWidth >> imageHeight ;` and multiply them to get dataSize.